# Prisma - Entity with several relations

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

I want to create a `Comment` entity that needs to be used in several entities, I have to create a relationship with each entity? or is there another way to make it better?

```js
model Comment {
  id String @id() @default(uuid())

  // n times per entity
  order   Order?  @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
  orderId String?
}
```

Comment: Yes you have to create a relationship with each entity.